# Window.innerwidth doesn't update on browser resize

Tags: javascript, html, resize, window, width

When i resize the window, the window.innerwidth doesn't update. I dont want to use jQuery.

```
var page = window.innerWidth;
var content = document.getElementById("content");
content.style.width = page - 300 + "px";
```

i tried:

```
window.addEvent("resize", function() {
  console.log(window.getCoordinates().width);
});
```

with no avail​

Edit: But that still doesn't fix the window.innerwidth not changing on resize

Comment: Depends on the browser. IE doesn't update dimensions until the resize event completes.

Comment: I didn't test in ie, only chrome and firefox

Answer (score 1):

It should rather be:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    console.log(window.innerWidth);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works in my browser:

```
<script>

    window.onresize = function() {    
        var widthWin = window.document.body.clientWidth;
        console.log(widthWin);         
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
  console.log(window.innerWidth);
};
```

But it will be called only after resizing is completed.

Comment: But that still doesn't fix the window.innerwidth not changing on resize

Comment: This does not address the issue here.