# Javascript and Svelte: updating elements by assignment. When does reactivity work?

Tags: javascript, dom, svelte

Consider the following svelte component

```
<script>
let x;
$: y = window.innerWidth;
</script>

<svelte.window bind:innerWidth={x} />

<h1>{x}</h1>
<h1>{y}</h1>
<h1>{window.innerWidth}</h1>
```

This renders three `h1` HTML elements, which show the `innerWidth` attribute of the window object.

However, only the first of them will update as you change the width of the window.

My question is **why don't the other approaches update as the window width changes?**

I'm new to javascript and svelte, but it looks as though <svelte.window /> is an import, which allows us to bind to the window object, which seems to allow us to "listen" to updates on window.innerWidth. But why not the other approaches? Why aren't they connected?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Window.innerwidth doesn't update on browser resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479494/window-innerwidth-doesnt-update-on-browser-resize)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svelte:window` is fairly magical<sup>1</sup> but in general the rule is that reactivity is limited to local state (variables declared in a component), props (e.g. here `bind:innerWidth`) and [stores](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store).

Since the other approaches access `window.innerWidth` which is none of the above, the state will not update. The `$:` cannot turn something that is not reactive into something reactive, it merely propagates existing reactivity.

---

<sup>1</sup>It internally uses events or observers to mimic the reactivity of regular Svelte components. It is not just reading `window` properties.

The list of events used for the `window` properties:

```js
const associated_events = {
    innerWidth: 'resize',
    innerHeight: 'resize',
    outerWidth: 'resize',
    outerHeight: 'resize',

    scrollX: 'scroll',
    scrollY: 'scroll'
};
```

[Source](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/dafbdc286eef3de2243088a9a826e6899e20465c/src/compiler/compile/render_dom/wrappers/Window.ts)

Comment: Can I clarify, perhaps a difference I wasn't aware of. In python, declaring X=window.innerWidth would point to that property, and therefore I would expect it's value to update as innerWidth updated. With JavaScript, you are assigning X as the value contained in innerWidth, unless you have observers monitoring for changes in the value

Comment: Python behaves the same as JS, primitive values are copied and there are references to objects. If you are using some library where `innerWidth` is a reference to an object, that is what you get, if it is primitive it simply is copied. Try e.g. this in the Python terminal: `x = 4; y = x; x = 0; print(y)`, the value of `y` will not be `0`, it will still be `4`, because that was the value at the time of the assignment.